# Ipython interpreter turns slow (Anaconda, Windows)

Tags: windows, ipython, interpreter, anaconda

I have some issues when using the Ipython interpreter in Windows (I use Anaconda). After a few minutes (and expecially after plotting graphs), the interpreter turns extremely slow (it writes about 1 letter/second, even when I paste the commands).

Moreover, the keyboard interruption sometimes sends me directly to the Windows interpreter (instaed of just interrupting the current task).

However, the processing time doesn't seem to be longer than usual, and I just have to quit Ipython and restart it (wothout closing the terminal) for the interpreter to work properly again. But, still, it comes back **every time** !

Do you know how I can fix this ?

Comment: Is this in the Windows console? If so, have you tried the [Qt Console](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/qtconsole.html) or a [Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) instead?